C++ iterator has a segmentation fault when using getter for linked list in a class
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
class A{
  private:
      list<int*> data;

  public:
      A(list<int*> data_){data=data_;}
      list<int*> getData(){return data;}
};

int main(){
  list<int*> temp;
  temp.push_back(new int(1));
  temp.push_back(new int(2));
  temp.push_back(new int(3));
  temp.push_back(new int(4));

  A a(temp);

  // First Iteration
  list<int*>::iterator it;
  cout<<(a.getData()).size()<<endl;
  for (it = (a.getData()).begin(); it != (a.getData()).end(); it++)
      cout << *(*it) << endl;
  
  // Second Iteration
  list<int*> mylist = a.getData();
  for (it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); it++)
      cout << *(*it) << endl;
}

The first iteration causes a segmentation fault, but the seance iteration doesn't. What causes the segmentation fault in the first iteration?

getData returns a copy of the list so those iterators point to different containers. Return a reference to the list instead.

See this answer.

Sidenote: why (a.getData()).begin() rather than a.getData().begin()?

Additional side-note: Why on Earth are you making a list of pointers to int? list is inefficient for most purposes to start with (vector or deque is usually better for the vast majority of use cases), but dynamically allocating it all as pointers to int rather than plain ints by value is fragmenting the hell out of your memory and risking leaks for no benefit I can see.

@ShadowRanger To answer your question, this is meant to be a toy example. The original use of the linked list is to store a pointer to another struct / class.

@AsherMai: Even in that case, you'd usually be better off storing the other struct/class by value, using emplace_back/emplace_front to get zero-copy behavior directly constructing into the list, without introducing an extra layer of indirection (and without risking memory leaks). One of the few benefits std::list offers over std::vector and std::deque is that it guarantees existing elements never move, even when elements are inserted in the middle of the list, and that benefit is worth much less for a pointer-sized element than it is for a more heavyweight struct/class.

The problem is that
list<int*> getData(){return data;}

Takes data which is a list and makes a copy of the list and returns that copy.
The class should say:
class A{
  private:
      list<int*> data;

  public:
      A(list<int*>& data_) : data(data) {}
      list<int*>& getData() {return data;}
};

So that copies are not made except when data is assigned a value.
You can try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/0qHTOAybI
